# for loop to show and write a bunch of images after some processing

Tags: python, opencv, for-loop, image-processing, transform

I'm using OpenCV+Python to transform a bunch of perspective view images to side view images.
I am trying to do this by writing for a loop.
Here I read the images

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob


img_dir="/path to /images/"
data_path=os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files=glob.glob(data_path)
data=[]
for f1 in files:
     img=cv2.imread(f1)
     data.append(img)

     cv2.circle(img, (465, 350), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
     # bot left
     cv2.circle(img, (1150, 665), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
     cv2.circle(img, (1200, 180), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
     cv2.circle(img, (445, 50), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

     pts1 = np.float32([[451, 66], [1194, 205], [472, 366], [1149, 644]])
     # pts1=np.float32([[440,50],[2000,185],[1600,1300],[460,500]])
     # pts2=np.float32([[0,0],[1920,0],[1920,1080],[0,1080]])
     pts2 = np.float32([[467, 308], [1138, 308], [467, 636], [1138, 636]])

     matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
     result = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (1920, 1080))
     cv2.imshow('rrr',result)
     cv2.waitKey(0)
     path = 'path to folder'
     cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'result.jpg'), result)
     cv2.waitKey(1)
```

**edited: I edited my code now I able to get all the output. MY question is how can I write all the images? it only saves one of the images**

Comment: `PImage.open()` is not OpenCV. The format loaded may not be compatible with OpenCV/Numpy format.

Comment: fmw42, could you please tell me what can I do?

Comment: Open the image with OpenCV (cv2.imread) rather than PImage. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html

Comment: I edited my post pls look at it.

Comment: Put `cv2.waitKey(0)` inside the loop, else the view window updates to fast for you to see.

Comment: Hey, J.D, I got it. Could you pls tell me how can I write all the images?

Comment: `cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'result.jpg'), result)` keeps overwriting the same file. Add a variable to the filename, such as a index number or use the original filename and add '_processed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to write all images:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

img_dir="path-to-source-folder"
data_path=os.path.join(img_dir,'*g')
files=glob.glob(data_path)
# data=[]

i = 0
for f1 in files:
     img=cv2.imread(f1)
     # data.append(img)

     cv2.circle(img, (465, 350), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
     # bot left
     cv2.circle(img, (1150, 665), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
     cv2.circle(img, (1200, 180), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
     cv2.circle(img, (445, 50), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)

     pts1 = np.float32([[451, 66], [1194, 205], [472, 366], [1149, 644]])
     # pts1=np.float32([[440,50],[2000,185],[1600,1300],[460,500]])
     # pts2=np.float32([[0,0],[1920,0],[1920,1080],[0,1080]])
     pts2 = np.float32([[467, 308], [1138, 308], [467, 636], [1138, 636]])

     matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1, pts2)
     result = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (1920, 1080))

     path = 'path-to-your-dest-folder'
     cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, 'result_'+str(i)+'.jpg'), result)
     i+=1

     cv2.imshow('rrr',result)
     cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```